# change the false to False and true to True in Python

Tags: json, api, python-3.6

I am working on the DRF and found that one API is returning data into json like:

```
{
    "runMode": true,
    "analyseOnly": false,
    "runDescription": "hello",
    "runDirectory": "/tmp",
}
```

Now I want to change the format in such a way that true becomes True and false becomes False, but as I tried to apply any changes to it, it gives some error which is obvious.

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined. Did you mean: 'True'?
```

I tried to change the API output json into string and replaced true with True and same for false and then again change the type of data into json using `ast.literal_eval` library. But it seems inappropriate and lengthy.

How to get rid of this error without changing the type of the API output (json). Any suggestions